# Developers OS license with MSDN Premium Subscription

Tags: windows

I have been looking at whether our **MSDN Premium Subscriptions** would cover upgrading our developer’s machines from Vista OEM to Win 7 RTM MSDN.

The assumption here is that *"design, develop, test, or demonstrate"* covers the developer’s day job, so should cover the OS.

I have found that other development shops seem to make this same assumption.

Having looked at the [MSDN Subscription Software Use Rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/subscriptions/cc150618.aspx) page this does not seem to be the case.

from the page :

> "Many MSDN subscribers use a computer for mixed use—both design, development, testing, and demonstration of your programs (the use allowed under the MSDN Subscription license)  and some **other use**.
>   Using the software in any other way, such as for **doing email, playing games, or editing a document** is another use and is not covered by the MSDN Subscription license.
>   When this happens, the underlying operating system must also be licensed normally by purchasing a regular copy of Windows such as the one that came with a new OEM PC"

So if you are not using the operating software install to purely *"design, develop, test"* read *"use your visual studio license"* and you answered a company email you are in violation of the license.

Is this indeed the case?

Is there a way that MSDN OS licenses can cover your day to day dev machine?

Did you make the same assumption as I did?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the interpretation of terms of use for a service, not programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that's the case. No you can't change the license.

Comment: well, i'll be damned... I wonder if it could be argued that developer emails, and document edits are done in support of "design, develop, test, or demonstrate"?

Comment: No. Hence the explanation on the rights page. It's not like this is new either.

Comment: @grenade And playing games increases moral and is thus in support of development too :D

Comment: See my later answer below with citations. I don't think this answer is correct any more.

Answer (score 2):

MSDN license has always been a "technical" license that restricts the usage to development "sandbox" only. Your primary workstation *must* be covered by a regular non-dev license. Although I *heard* of some shops that (purposefully or not) violate this license and are very happy with the savings.

Comment: Note however that there are some exceptions. Specifically: "If you have an MSDN Premium subscription, you can also install and use one copy of certain desktop applications on one device for *any purpose*." - those "certain desktop applications" are those from the Office suite.

Comment: Pavel, that's right but you still need to buy the OS to run the Outlook on.

Comment: TFS 2010 was added to the list of "Production" use applications (like Office is)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this document](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13350&6B49FDFB-8E5B-4B07-BC31-15695C5A2143=1) the accepted answer no longer appears to hold true (at least for licensed users of Visual Studio **Enterprise** with MSDN).

Relevant excerpt (p13) says:

> ### Production use of Office Professional Plus 2016
>
> *Office Professional Plus 2016 can be used by licensed users of Visual Studio Enterprise with MSDN or Visual Studio Enterprise – annual on
>   one device for production use*

From [this page](https://products.office.com/en-us/professional) the Office Professional Plus SKU contains Outlook, and although IANAL it would seem that use of Outlook is now allowed with an MSDN subscription.

With regard to the underlying OS this remains excluded. The relevant text from the licensing document says:

> *When there is mixed use the underlying operating system must be licensed normally by purchasing a regular copy of Windows such as the
>   one that came with a new OEM PC.*